# document.getElementsByTagName() contains undefined item

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ecmascript-6

I wrote some ES6 code that should be able to read a template from a `<script type="text/template" data-id="template-id"></script>`-tag, pass it through Handlebars and replace every `<template data-id="template-id" data-ctx='{"some": "json"}>`-tag by the template with given ID, while also filling in the context into the according `{{ expressions }}` in the template.

I added dependencies to the TemplateManager class so I can add `<template>`-tags within a `<script type="text/template">`-tag and it will still be rendered correctly (see the code for an example).

```js
class TemplateManager {

    constructor () {

        this.templates = { }
        this.dependencies = {  }

    }

    addTemplate (id) {

        if (this.templates.hasOwnProperty(id))
            throw new Error('Template with ID "' + id + '" already exists!')

        this.templates[id] = new Template(id)

    }

    removeTemplate (id) {

        delete this.templates[id]

    }

    update (id) {

        if (!this.templates.hasOwnProperty(id))
            throw new Error('No template with ID "' + id + '" exists!')

        this.templates[id].update()

        if (this.dependencies.hasOwnProperty(id)) {

            Object.keys(this.dependencies[id]).map((i) =>
                this.update(this.dependencies[id][i])
            )

        }

    }

    addDependency (id, dependentOn) {

        if (!this.dependencies.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            this.dependencies[id] = [  ]
        }

        Object.keys(dependentOn).map((i) => {

            if (this.dependencies.hasOwnProperty(dependentOn[i]) && this.dependencies[dependentOn[i]].indexOf(id))
                throw new Error('Circular dependencies detected!')

            if (this.dependencies[id].indexOf(dependentOn[i]) == -1)
                this.dependencies[id].push(dependentOn[i])

        })

    }

}

class Template {

    constructor (id) {

        this.id = id
        this.template = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById(id).innerHTML)

    }

    update () {

        let templateElems = document.getElementsByTagName('template')
        
        if (templateElems.length < 1)
            return

        Object.keys(templateElems).map((keyTmpl) => {

            let templateElem = templateElems[keyTmpl],
                div, ctx

            if (!templateElem.attributes.hasOwnProperty('data-id')) {
                throw new Error('A template tag needs a "data-id" attribute!')
                throw new Error(templateElem)
            }

            ctx = templateElem.attributes.hasOwnProperty('data-ctx')
                ? JSON.parse(templateElem.attributes['data-ctx'].value)
                : {}

            if (templateElem.attributes['data-id'].value.trim() != this.id)
                return

            div = document.createElement('div')
            div.innerHTML = this.template(ctx)

            templateElem.parentNode.replaceChild(div, templateElem)

        })

    }

}

let manager = new TemplateManager()
manager.addTemplate('a')
manager.addTemplate('b')
manager.addDependency('a', [ 'b' ])
manager.update('a')
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Bug</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <template data-id="a" data-ctx='{"name":"World"}'></template>
  <script type="text/template" id="a">
   <h1>Hello, {{name}}!</h1>
   <template data-id="b" data-ctx='{"place":"the Internet"}'></template>
   <template data-id="b" data-ctx='{"place":"my house"}'></template>
  </script>
  <script type="text/template" id="b">
   <h2>Welcome to {{place}}</h2>
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.10/handlebars.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

If I now try to run this code, the first `<template>`-tag in the template with ID `a` renders correctly, the second one however does not and just throws a `TypeError: templateElem is undefined` on line 83. When logging the `templateElems` (same scope) to the console, the returned object has a length of 2, while the second item is undefined.

Why is this, and how can I prevent the error from happening?

PS.: For convenience, here is the plain code served from github pages so the code can be stepped through using the debugger more easily: https://theplatzhalter.github.io/fiddle/templating/

Comment: `Object.keys(templateElems)` better to use Array.from() and you should NOT use map() to loop.

Comment: Once you remove the `<template>` element from the DOM, it's no longer in the collection. It's generally better to iterate backwards (`for( var i=collection.length-1; i>=0; i--)`) for this reason.

Comment: Not really the issue here, but you can add `return this` to your methods to chain them accordingly.

Comment: @entiendoNull Yes, I did that already in my "real code", just didn't update the snippet. Thank you very much anyway!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Will try that now, thank you!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That one worked! I did not think it would be this easy. Would you mind posting an answer so I can upvote and accept it?